# Density of multivariate normal given linear condition

Tags: multivariate-analysis, kalman-filter

Given a variable $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$

What is the density of $X$ given $HX = d$,
$H$ and $d$ both constant

I.e. we observe $X$ with rank-deficient linear operator $H$ and obtain some value $d$. Given this knowledge how do we update our knowledge/distribution of $X$?

This is just one of the steps in the [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#The_Kalman_filter). I'm having trouble separating it out.

Ideally an answer would be analytic forms for both $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ after the update plus a rationale/derivation or link to such a derivation.

Comment: Why $d$ is constant? A function of random vector $X$ will be a random vector $d$, isn't it? So if you observe $X$ this additional knowledge do not give more insights on $X$ distribution. There are also many good implementations of Kalman things, are you just curious in theory or want to make a program yourself?

Comment: $H$ is a row vector? $d$ is a scalar ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept that this `b` value has a variance, then the problem is solved.

The standard Kalman filter [update step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Update) can handle non-square sensor-to-measurement matrices. You're already calling it 'H' so you're on the right track.

You Just might need to include a finite variance on `b` or you'll end up with a degenerate (non-positive definite <--> one or more zero-Eigen-value) covariance matrix after the update step, and that may cause you problems elsewhere.

I bet that if you consider the variance of `b` to be zero the result will be identical to rotating the system so your slice is axis-aligned, and then running the Gaussian slice algorithm shown in Andrew Moore's [data mining slides](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/), and then rotating back to the original coordinate space. See the section on Gaussian  (http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/gaussian.html).

If this isn't your only sensor just remember that the Kalman-filter update step is Bayesian inference (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference), and your simulation state is just a sensor. If your sensors errors are uncorrelated (which they should be or the basic Kalman filter won't be quite right) it doesn't matter what order you 'update' them together because a Bayseian update is commutative (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) and associative (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associativity).

Sorry about the links, I don't have enough points to post more than two.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do this first. From the definition

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definition

the random vector $(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ is $N(\mu,\Sigma)$, where $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\Sigma$ is a $k\times k$ positive definite matrix with $\mathrm{rank}(\Sigma)=\ell$, if and only if $X=CZ+\mu$, where $Z_1,\dots,Z_k$ are independent $N(0,1)$, and $C$ is a $k\times \ell$ matrix such that $\Sigma = CC^\top$.

Use this to find the distribution of $HX = HCZ + H\mu$.